# Rails Turbolinks: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

Whenever I make any changes to the stylesheet folder or javascript folder in my rails product, I get this error:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - ../tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/v3.0/si/siow_16RK0wQxrUQUsNhDLM2Y8GT8L_ondyAZnxDiwc.cache.47238010484320.5052.306984
```

It's a problem with Turbolinks and either flags an error with this line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Or this one:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => false %>
```

It's even done it by adding images into the /images folder. I'm also finding it difficult to debug, as I undo what I've changed since the page was working and sometimes that doesn't resolve the issue. Therefore, I'm wondering if it's too do with rails not identifiyng new files or changes that I've made.

I've been constantly getting this, so any help will be much appreciated.

Also if anyone knows any good bebugging tools for rails that'll also be very helpful. As turbolinks/sprockets is giving me nothing.

Comment: what is Rails version ?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk 2.6.2

Comment: @OlegSobchuk I've got more reason to believe part of the error is to do with rails updating the files that I've changed when it compiles, as sometimes I just need to reload the page for it to load correctly.

Comment: Rails version 2.6 ? Are you sure?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk Yes, pretty sure. It's what my ruby -v says. I think it was an error with directions to javascript files in application.js and application.scss. However, having the same error every time isn't helpful.

Comment: @Toby that is the `ruby` version not the rails version.

Comment: @engineersmnky apologies I miss read. My rails is 5.1.7

Comment: Do you have proper permission for the assets folder? Sometimes when I compile the assets the permissions get messed up and end up with that message.